# jQuery plugins in brunch.io

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, brunch

I'm developing an application using `brunch.io` and want to use a jquery plugin (in this case the **jQuery Waypoints plugin**).
What is the recommended way of doing this?

I know it is possible to get the plugin through

```
npm install waypoints
```

But that doesn't make `$('.my-div').waypoint()` work in my app.

Thank You

Comment: Are you including your file into your page anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

place the plugin into `vendor/scripts` and that’s all

Comment: Hi Paul - thank you for this answer. Unfortunately I have tried this. When I place the file waypoints.js in vendor/scripts and a `require "scripts/vendor/waypoints.js"` or `require 'waypoints.js'` I get a `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "scripts/vendor/waypoints.js"` in my chrome inspector. I'm using brunch with hipsters template if that does any difference.

Comment: Aaah - I get it. No need to require as it is available globally. Thank You. And thank You for brunch. It's a great tool.

Comment: I did this and am getting errors in the console that `$` is undefined in the plugin scripts. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Brunch now supports Bower, so adding Waypoints can be done like so:

```
bower install --save jquery-waypoints
```

As of version `2.0.3` Waypoints doesn't specify a `main` in its `bower.json`, so you'll need to specify a `main` in the `overrides` section of your app's `bower.json` to indicate which file Brunch should use as the entry point to the installed package, e.g. `"jquery-waypoints": { "main": "waypoints.min.js" }`.

Of course, this will not work if you're using a version of Brunch without Bower support.